# Using multibib and natbib for French bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, french, multibib

I want two separate bibliographies in my work. I have used the package multibib to create my bibliography. The problem is that I am using `natbib` because my bibliography style requires it (francais.bst available here: ctan.org/pkg/francais-bst)

When I compile my file (for the first time with pdfLaTeX), I get this error[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{B1}{Reference Book1}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{francais}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[defaultlines=3,all]{nowidow}


\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}
The apples are green. \citepB1{ABF-19-35} Here there are!\citep{DEFQ-243}

\bibliographyB1{Book1}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Reference Book2}
\bibliography{Book2}

\end{document}
```

And my .bib files:
Book1:

```
@InBook{ABF-19-35,
  chapter   = {1:Qu'est-ce qui fait pousser la forêt},
  pages     = {19},
  title     = {Arbres et plantes forestières du Québec et des maritimes},
  publisher = {Éditions Michel Quintin},
  year      = {2007},
  author    = {Michel Leboeuf},
  editor    = {Johanne Ménard},
  note      = {ISBN: 978-2-89435-331-8},
}
```

Book2:

```
@InBook{DEFQ-243,
  chapter   = {Glossaire: description écologique des forêts du Québec},
  pages     = {243},
  title     = {Description écologique des forêts du Québec},
  publisher = {Centre collégial de développement de matériel didactique (CCDMD)},
  year      = {2007},
  author    = {Ph.D. Madeleine Couboue},
  note      = {ISBN: 978-2-89470-219-2},
}
```

If someone is able to help me with this to get something like this: [image]

Answer (score 1):

In general, TeX commands starting with letter cannot contain numbers. Hence in your case it is not the matter of 'natbib`, but`\citeB1`and so on. In my example the style`alpha`simulates`natbib`, as you can expect many problems with using it with`multibib`. If you only need citations of the form`(key)`, it might be a good simulation of`natbib` behaviour.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{B1}{Reference Book1}
\newcites{B}{Reference Book1}

%\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{francais}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[defaultlines=3,all]{nowidow}


\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
%\def\@cite#1#2{[{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}
\def\@cite#1#2{({#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi})} %square to rounded - PS
\makeatother

The apples are green. 
%\citepB1{ABF-19-35} Here there are!\citep{DEFQ-243}
\citeB{ABF-19-35} Here there are!\cite{DEFQ-243}

%\bibliographyB1{Book1}
\bibliographyB{Book1}
\bibliographystyleB{alpha}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Reference Book2}
\bibliography{Book2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The only problem in this code, is that the first reference [Leb07]is using the word "chapter" rather than "chap." as the `francais.bst`file should do. Also, in the text, French references should look like : " (Leboeuf, 2007)" Do you think that it will still possible to use `natbib`  ?

Comment: @Matt Oh! So you really need natbib or some Harvard style! It is really difficult. Replacing you macros according to suggestions from my partial answer, you can decide, if the obstacles are acceptable.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am stuck with a precise reference style. Do you know an alternative command of `multibib` that could work with `natbib`?  Do you have any idea why `multibib` and `natbib`are not compatible together?